# C initializing array of structure error

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to initialize int array in struct but when I take a value from `scanf` then access to values it's give me `warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]` error. This is the my code:

```
struct maclar {
    int macNo[40];
    int evSahibi[40];
    int deplasman[40];
} mac[40];

void verileriAl(FILE *mp) {
    for (int i = 0; fscanf(mp,"%d %d %d",
                           mac[i].macNo, mac[i].evSahibi, mac[i].deplasman) != -1; i++) {
        ........codes here .....
    }
}

main() {
    FILE *mp = fopen("maclar.txt", "r");
    verileriAl(mp);
    printf("%d\n", mac[0].macNo);  //give me warning and wrong value
}
```

Comment: in general, the definition of a struct should be kept separate from the declaration of the struct instance.

Comment: when calling any of the scanf family of fucntions,  check for (in this case) 3.  Any other returned value means an error occurred

Comment: the function: `main()` when run on an OS, only has 2 valid and one optional signature.  All those signatures have a `int` return type.  With out a OS, the only valid return type is `void`

Comment: when calling `fopen()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a array of `int` to `printf` for the `%d` format, hence the format mismatch. It is a good thing you compile with appropriate warnings, otherwise this error would go unnoticed.

Why do you make your structure hold arrays of 40 values for each member?

This is probably an error, out of confusion.

Fix your code this way:

```
struct maclar {
    int macNo;
    int evSahibi;
    int deplasman;
} mac[40];

int verileriAl(FILE *mp) {
    int i;

    if (mp == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (i = 0; i < 40 && fscanf(mp,"%d %d %d", 
            &mac[i].macNo, &mac[i].evSahibi, &mac[i].deplasman) == 3; i++) {
        continue;
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *mp = fopen("maclar.txt", "r");
    if (mp != NULL) {
        if (verileriAl(mp) > 0)
            printf("%d\n", mac[0].macNo);
        fclose(mp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Yasin  This answer's change to `== 3` versus original `!= -1` is also an important code improvement.  Test for the one value you want instead of testing for one of the many values you do not want.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are passing `mac[i].macNo` which converts to `int *` type. `%d` expects `int` type argument.

Also note that you are doing the same mistake in `fscanf`. One of the possible solution is to declare `mac` as

```
struct maclar
{
    int macNo[40];
    int evSahibi[40];
    int deplasman[40];
}mac;
```

Now change `for` statement to

```
for (int i = 0; fscanf(mp,"%d %d %d",mac.macNo[i],mac.evSahibi[i],mac.deplasman[i]) != -1 ; i++)
```

and change `printf` call to

```
printf("%d\n", mac.macNo[0]);
```

Comment: @Yasin; Updated the answer.

Comment: This does not look like the correct fix... Better make `mac` an array of structures with 3 int members.

Comment: @chqrlie; It is difficult to say without knowing the intent of the program.

Comment: @haccks: I agree its difficult, but it seems to make more sense to have an array if structures instead of a structure of arrays... My biassed opinion of course.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because the format `%d` of scanf reads *just one* `int`, but you try to assign this value to an array of `int`s. You cannot put a value into an array without specifying the index.*

   *edit: Actually the value will just be put into the first index as because* `int *` *is evaluated.*
2. As [haccks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34474374/1548311) answered: The real problem is printf, because it expects an argument of type `int` rather than `int *`.

Comment: That's true, but not the reason.

Comment: it is  fscanf() and as I know that it's available

Answer (score 0):

regarding this line:

```
printf("%d\n", mac[0].macNo);
```

the field `macNo` is an array of `int`

In C, a reference to the array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.

So this: `mac[0].macNo` results in an address.

the format specifier: `%d` will not properly handle an address.

suggest:

```
printf("%p\n", mac[0].macNo);
```

because `%p` is specifically for printing an address